# Find a point, using the differences between distances from 3 other points

Tags: euclidean-geometry

I have 3 points on a 2D plane ($A$, $B$ and $C$), with known co-ordinates $(x_A, y_A)$, $(x_B, y_B)$ and $(x_C, y_C)$.

I need to find the co-ordinates $(x_Z, y_Z)$ of point $Z$.
I know the differences between each pair of distances from points $A$, $B$ and $C$:
$|\overline{AZ} - \overline{BZ}|$, $|\overline{AZ} - \overline{CZ}|$ and $|\overline{BZ} - \overline{CZ}|$.

Is point $Z$ unique from this information, and if so, how can the co-ordinates of $Z$ be found?

Thank you in advance.

*(Sorry I can't supply an image, the image uploader is refusing to work!!)*

Comment: you could try using TeX for images: $\style {background-color:red}{\begin{smallmatrix}&&\\&&&\\&&&\\&&&\end{smallmatrix}}$

Comment: Hint: The locus of the points with constant difference between the distances with two points (with absolute value) is an hyperbola